# How to factorise $x^5-5x^4+1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I know, one way is to look for the roots of the corresponding quintin equation: $x^5-5x^4+1=0.$ But the roots can be found using numerical methods only and these won't help here. Is there any other way to get the job done? Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a method named after Kronecker, but it is time consuming if you do it by hand. Usually, computer programs are used to find such factorizations. In this case, ther poynomial cannot be factored (it is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$) and since its galois group is $S_5$, the equation cannot be solved by radicals.

Comment: Yes got it, thanks both of you!